# Fieldset and Definition List

Tags: html

Should a fieldset be used as well as a definition list, is the dl tag doing the job of the fieldset - what is best practice?

```
<fieldset>
    <dl>
        <dt>Order By</dt>
        <dd><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 1</label></dd>
        <dd><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 2</label></dd>
        <dd><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 3</label></dd>
    </dl>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on whether it is semantically "right" or "wrong" to have a dl within a fieldset in this context. However, it is a bit unusual.

That being said, the dt looks like it really ought to be a legend instead, which is designed specifically for labeling entire fieldsets. Consequently, the dl and dd elements should be replaced with a series of paragraphs:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Order By</legend>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 1</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 2</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 3</label></p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @panthro: There is nothing wrong with using p elements in a form. In fact, the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html) uses them throughout most of the examples. You don't have to think of "paragraph" in the strictest sense of the word - you could simply think of it as a block of text, or something more generic (but still more restricted than say a div).

Answer (score 0):

The `<fieldset>` tag is used to group related elements in a form  and `<legend>` to caption a fieldset.

Note: Do not use `<dl>` element or `<ul>` element to create the indentation.
Though it works, it is a bad practice.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Order by</legend>      
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 1</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 2</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG1x" id="checkboxG1x"/><label for="checkboxG1x" class="checkbox-label">Option 3</label><br/>
</fieldset>
```